# Linear system of equations over $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, finite-fields

I had the following set of simultaneous equations in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

> $$3x+5y=1$$ $$4x-5y=5$$

Now adding them we get

> $$7x=6$$

And this has no integer solution in $x$ since $7$ and $6$ are coprime.

Would it then be sufficient and correct to then conclude that the system has no solutions over $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Furthermore, is there a way of determining if a set of simultaneous equations has a solution over some $\mathbb{Z}_n$ without explicitly trying to find solutions and discovering that the system does not work?

Comment: Seven and six being coprime is not a problem for the solvability of the congruence $7x\equiv6$. A serious problem is that the coefficient of $x$ ($7$) and the modulus (also $7$) are NOT coprime. Remember that in $\Bbb{Z}_7$ we have $7=0$, so basically you get the equation $0x=6$ by eliminating $y$. This also shows in the determinant calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the usual tools from linear algebra. You have a system of 2 linear equations in $\mathbb{Z}_7$. Just take the determinant!

$$\begin{vmatrix}3 & 5 \\ 4 & -5\end{vmatrix} = -15-20=-35 = 0 \pmod 7$$

Zero! So, the rank of system's matrix is 1. What about the augmented matrix $\begin{pmatrix}3 & 5 & 1 \\ 4 & -5 & 5\end{pmatrix}$?

$$\begin{vmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 4 & 5\end{vmatrix} = 15 - 4 = 11 = 4 \pmod 7$$

It has a non-zero minor of maximum rank, so has rank 2. Since the ranks differ, the system is inconsistent, and has no solutions.

Comment: The determinant completely slipped my mind! Thanks for the great idea.